# The ViewVontroller order of this iPhone project

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, modal-dialog, segue

I am having problem of deciding the order flow of this project. There are 3 ViewControllers.

1. ImageVC
2. WebVC
3. LoginVC

---

what I want to do is, when app starts, open/stays in the **ImageVC** while checking for network connection, if no network, keep on popping up the alert until there are network available.

once network available, check and see if there are appropriate username/password stored in keychain, if yes, directly go to **WebVC**, else go to **LoginVC**

**WebVC** has a logout which allow user to go back to **LoginVC**

so as long as there are username/password stored, it will go directly go **WebVC**

whats the order of the segue(using modal segue here)?

ImageVC -> WebVC -> LoginVC?
or
WebVC -> ImageVC -> LoginVC?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the imageVC is, but why don't you load the app into a loginVC, then press submit to check credentials, (show loading HUD while it checks credentials), then if correct, load the webVC. The ImageVC doesn't seem to have a purpose right now.

When the loginVC loads, you can check the connection asynchronously so you don't freeze the UI, then if you get a yes, then you know to proceed with the password check, otherwise don't bother.

Popping up a no network alert more than once is a bad idea (annoying). Maybe find a subtle way to do it (a red or green light? if the user needs to know, if not then just pop it once, and only pop it again after the user tries the password again).

LoginVC-->webVC

imageVC seems to have no purpose here